# I have this problem in Ruby on Rails SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I try to make tags and have the option to delete the tag. When I want to destroy the tag, I get this error SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed.

ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in TagsController#destroy

Here are my code for delete tag in controller:

```
def destroy
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @tag.destroy

    flash.notice = "Tag '#{@tag.name}' Deleted!"
    
    redirect_to tags_path
end
```

This is the schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_03_20_115719) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "author_name"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "article_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"
  end

  create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tag_id", null: false
    t.integer "article_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["article_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_article_id"
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "articles"
  add_foreign_key "taggings", "articles"
  add_foreign_key "taggings", "tags"
end
```

Comment: You need to post your `schema.rb` stuff for `Tag`. Most likely you set a constraint in another table to refer to a `Tag`.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek I fill question with the schema. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A failed FOREIGN KEY constraint usually means that you have another record in your database that still has a `belongs_to` association set to this record and therefore you cannot delete it.

In your example, there is an `article` tagged with the tag you are trying to delete.

```
create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "tag_id", null: false        # << here the association
  t.integer "article_id", null: false

# in combination with

add_foreign_key "taggings", "articles"
add_foreign_key "taggings", "tags"       # << here the foreign key constraint
```

Your `schema.rb` shows that you have a `taggings` join table that connects articles with tags and in this table, both attributes (the `tag_id` and the `article_id`) cannot be `nil` and must contain a valid id that identifies a record on the associated table.

That means when you want to delete a specific tag then you have to remove the tag from the `taggings` join table first. The following code should work:

```
def destroy
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @tag.articles.clear                    # << add this line
  @tag.destroy

  flash.notice = "Tag '#{@tag.name}' Deleted!"

  redirect_to tags_path
end
```

Read about [`collection.clear`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-and-belongs-to-many-collection-clear) and the usage of the `has_and_belongs_to` association in general in the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. I filled my question with schema.rb code

Comment: @MarcMarc I updated my answer after reading your database schema to provide a more specific solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @spickermann. This helped me and now works.